# How to make best use of Triglav Protector in HotS

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I'm looking for details about how to best use the Triglav protector, as both the pilot and the gunner.  The wiki lacks damage numbers on the gunner abilities, and in the middle of a game I'm too busy fighting to look closely at the numbers; so that makes it rather hard to figure out the optimal rotation for the gunner.

When should it be used to target heroes vs buildings, should I charge the same structure or move between structures when shield is on cool down.  what combinations of abilities for the gunner has best dps for either buildings or vs players?  Basically how do I make sure I'm not wasting the protector if I hop in to pilot it?

Answer (score 1):

According to some top ranked players that I follow on Twitch and other sites, and to my own experience.

First - don't use the Protector as a tank for your team, as generally the enemy team will focus on taking him down.

***As the Pilot:***

> Charge and attack the towers, in a line if you are getting the south tower attack from the lower part of the tower, so the north tower can't reach you (this is useful with Dragon Knight also). Use the "hand" to disable the tower or to push an enemy attacker hero away. Protect allied heroes with the shield only if they are close, don't chase anyone, as the protector is an easy target. So use the time to take down buildings.
> And Finally, if you are under heavy attack move to another line and repeat.

***As the Gunner:***

> Take care of the protector, shoot energy bombs to the buildings or to an enemy hero if you have a better chance to kill someone. Reserve the laser for enemy heroes as is more effective than in buildings. Use minigun to defend protector from melee heroes or use it in buildings if there's no threat for the protector.

Basically you need to keep moving, doing siege damage and watch out for attackers. I've seen some players that can take down 2 keeps and 4 towers with a single Triglav Protector attack. That means a lot of advantage for your team.